# Null user input on subquery criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I'm relatively new to SQL and trying to design a query for a database of 3 tables I created (A, B, and C).  It is a query allowing a user to input two parameters (date and line) from table A where all records are returned if the user leaves the line input blank.  This works great.

Now my problem is that I have included two subqueries as well.  These are querying tables B and C respectively with shared parameter inputs to the first query.  I can't get the results to show up properly if I try to allow a null user input to return all records.

1. The statement for the main query that works:

   ```
   HAVING (((A.Line)=[Enter Line]) AND ((A.Day)>=[Start Date] And (A.Day)<=[End Date])) OR (((A.Day)>=[Start Date] And (A.Day)<=[End Date]) AND (([A].[line] Like [Enter Line]) Is Null))
   ```
2. Trying the same thing using where or having on the subqueries does not work:

   ```
   where (b.day)>=[Start Date] And (b.day)<=[End Date] And b.line=[Enter Line] or (((b.Day)>=[Start Date] And (b.Day)<=[End Date]) AND ([b].[line] Like [Enter Line]) Is Null))
   ```

The subqueries work fine and return the correct results if I remove the or statement that tries to account for null input, but then I am unable to return all records when the user input is blank.

I appreciate any help!  I realize this is probably very messy and inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (b.day)>=[Start Date] 
  And (b.day)<=[End Date] 
  And b.line=[Enter Line] 
   or (...)
```

You are combining `And` with `or` in the same statement without using parenthesis to explicitly set the logical precedence.  Try this:

```
WHERE (    (b.day)>=[Start Date] 
       And (b.day)<=[End Date] 
       And b.line=[Enter Line] 
      ) or (...)
```